# Is the dbms_random.random in Oracle 11g a random function?

Tags: oracle11g

How can I select random number of records? When I use DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM and I order by this, the records isn't random. OK, I have 1000 record what I want, but I see ID is not random... Why? Do you know a another really random function in Oracle 11g? How can I get a random 1000 records from whole table.

My way:

```
SELECT ... FROM TAB1 INNER JOIN TAB2 ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID ORDER BY
DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
```

I use DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE too, but it's the same result.

> Example result: ID 33 54 68 90 37 50 66 93 ...

As if it take a partition and then it make a orber by DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM. Thanks for help!

Comment: It is random... are you wanting to perform your SELECT on 10 random IDs or randomly order the result as these are 2 different things...

Comment: If that is not random, then what is your definition of random?

Comment: So are you getting the same 1000 rows each time, but ordered differently? Where are you restricting the number of rows - you haven't shown a rownum filter, for example, but I suspect you're doing that at the wrong point.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I select random number of records?

**DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE** will return rows randomly, when order by is specified along with it, it orders randomly.

```
SQL> SELECT empno FROM emp ORDER BY empno;

     EMPNO
----------
      7369
      7499
      7521
      7566
      7654
      7698
      7782
      7788
      7839
      7844
      7876
      7900
      7902
      7934

14 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT empno FROM(
  2  SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE)
  3  WHERE ROWNUM <=10
  4  /

     EMPNO
----------
      7654
      7902
      7782
      7566
      7839
      7369
      7900
      7499
      7876
      7844

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

so, you get random ordering of rows.

Comment: Yes, that is for me random, because I don't see partition. Do you understand? In my results I see a random IDs, but in blocks from 1 to 100, from 100 to 200 etc. I want a random records from 1 to 1000. And when I select additional column (1,0) I have accidental distribution 500:500... Maybe I can't use the joins or...